# storage.cloud.google.com - Cookie Authentication - HTTP 403 / Permission Denied when browser signed in with multiple identities

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a user who is signed in to google with multiple accounts.

The first one is a personal address, the second one is the one that has permission to the bucket with the Cloud Storage Viewer role.

On visiting a valid cloud storage URL (of the form https://storage.cloud.google.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]) the user receives a 403 error.

I have been able to reproduce the situation using a similar combination of accounts.

If I log in with the Cloud Storage Viewer role'd account first I can access the resource.

Is there a way to make cookie authentication support multiple accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user wants to copy and paste the URL link between the 2 accounts, they can work with [Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). This way the personal address won't get the ‘403 / Permission Denied’ error and the user has access to the Cloud Storage URL. If the user doesn't want to have access with the personal account, they can create 2 [Chrome browser profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and switch between them instead of having a single Chrome session with multiple accounts signed in. These are the recommendations since it's not possible to have cookie-based authentication without granting Storage Object Viewer role.

Comment: The question is about making the link work with multiple accounts and using cloud storage with cookie authentication. I don't want to use signed URL for performance reasons and I certainly don't want to be asking users to sign in in specific ways.

Comment: Based on the [cookie-based authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/cookie-based-authentication), it doesn’t seem to have additional options without granting the Storage Object Viewer role.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but I still think it is clearer to note that cookie based authentication has an issue with multiple sign in.