# Google Cloud Storage file not accessible using second gmail user login

Tags: gmail, google-cloud-storage

We are using google cloud storage for file storage. We use domain permission to give permission to our company users. When I login with multiple accounts 1 personal account 2 company account storage files are not accessible while google drive file are accessible. How we can solve this?

file path - [https://storage.cloud.google.com/{bucket}/{filename}](https://storage.cloud.google.com/%7Bbucket%7D/%7Bfilename%7D)

```html
<img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/{bucket}/{filename}">
```

Comment: Google Cloud Storage authorization is via IAM Roles. What permissions are you granting to the users? How are you accessing the endpoint and with what type of credentials? Edit your question with details and show the code. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication

Comment: hi @JohnHanley our images are in storage with readonly access to mydomain.com. We are using img tag to display these images. When we login with our domain account it is working fine. But when we login with 2 accounts then we face issue. First my gmail account then my domain account. When we reverse the login order in that case files are accessible.

Comment: As @John Hanley mentioned, please share the code so we can help you better.

Comment: Based on the details in your question, you are not authorizing requests. Instead, you are relying upon the side-effects of browser cookies from previous authorizations.

Comment: Yes it is based on google cookies. Is it possible to authorizing request here?

Comment: I do not have experience with Cloud Storage cookie authentication. See this link for more information: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#cookieauth and https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies See this answer regarding problems with multiple identities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915789/storage-cloud-google-com-cookie-authentication-http-403-permission-denied